# Why does omitting update() from the sprite class affect group method calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

`self.groupofsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()`

If every sprite in the group above were a class, and I wished to update them all in some way, I would call `self.groupofsprites.update()`.

Must the update() method be defined in the sprite's class? Omitting it from the class causes no exceptions, but what normally would have updated now does not. Attempting to call other methods (e.g. `self.groupofsprites.changecolor()`) returns an AttributeError.

Comment: read doc: [Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) - it has defined `.update()` but not `.changecolor()` . You would have to define own `class MyGroup(Group)` with method `.changecolor()` And all `Sprites` in group would have to defined method `.changecolor()` too. [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) already has `.update()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read doc: [Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)

`Group` already has method `.update()`. And this method runs `.update()` in every element in group. If you put `Sprite`s which as default have (empty) method `.update()` then it works without problem. If you want to put other class then you have to define `.update()` in this class too.

`Group()` doesn't have method `.changecolor()` and you would have to define own 
`class MyGroup(Group)` with method `.changecolor()`. If this method will execute `.changecolor()` for every element in group then you will have to put class which has this method - and then it will also work without error.